# saving state of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function which shows me elements and starts to show more which when clicks displays all the list

I am trying to save its state in a browser when I have the show more clicked, it should save its state and upon page load should display all

this is my function

```
function slt(LessMore)
{
   var smH = 0;
    $(document).find('.sl > dd:lt(3)').each(function () {
        smH += $(this).outerHeight();
    });

    $('.sl').css({
        'max-height': smH + 34,
        'overflow': 'hidden'
    });
}
```

html of that is:

```
<dl class="sl" style="max-height: 34px; overflow: hidden;">
          <dt>Life</dt>
                    
              <dd>
                <label>
                    
                    <input type="checkbox">
                  
                  <div>Local <span>(4)</span></div>
                </label>
              </dd>
                    
              <dd>
                <label>
                    
                    <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  
                  <div>Sports <span>(4)</span></div>
                </label>
              </dd>
                    
              <dd>
                <label>
                    
                    <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  
                  <div>Origin <span>(9)</span></div>
                </label>
              </dd>
                    
              <dd>
                <label>
                    
                    <input type="checkbox" value=" Free">
                  
                  <div> Free Tickets <span>(9)</span></div>
                </label>
              </dd>
                    
              <dd>
                <label>
                    
                    <input type="checkbox" value=" Free">
                  
                  <div> Free Pages<span>(8)</span></div>
                </label>
              </dd>
                   
             
       </dl>
       
       <div class="branc_btn"><span class="see-all"><a href="#" onclick="slt(1);return false;">See More</a> </span><span class="see_less"><a href="#" onclick="slt(1);return false;">See Less</a></span></div>
```

Comment: try using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to persist the data

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to take a look at localStorage or sessionStorage? That should help you save states that persist in the browser.

E.g.

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage
```

Comment: thanks, i read the links you gave me but i am not so sure where and how i had to implement this